# sudo: unable to resolve host

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, sudo, raspberrypi

I am trying to set up a Ubuntu server on Raspberry Pi 2, but at the moment I am stuck with this:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
```

`/etc/hostname` says this:

```
ubuntu
```

`/etc/hosts` says this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I have seen solutions where one can go into recovery mode and change the password and change the hosts, but I don't think I can do that on server version on Raspberry Pi 2. Or can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add next line into `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
```

Comment: I cannot. For that I would need sudo access......and I have to appologize, it worked :)